# Excel select a value from a cell having row number calculated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A i have numbers calculated like so:

```
[A]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[1]
[2]
[3]
...
```

In column K I have values:

```
[row] [K]
[ 1 ] [7]
[ 2 ] [3]
[ 3 ] [6]
[ 4 ] [9]
```

How could I pull values from column K given that row number is the number stored in column A?
I have tried using Address() and Cell() like so:

```
=Cell("contents",ADDRESS(A5,11))
```

ADDRESS supposed to return a reference to given cell provided row and column numbers (that can be taken from other cells), CELL supposed to take reference and return detail about the cell referenced (here "content" and thus value). If I use it like so:

```
=Cell("contents", K4)
```

it gives me '9', when I use ADDRESS:

```
=ADDRESS(A4,11)
```

it gives me $K$4. But when I use them together I get an error.

Comment: Can't provide a full answer right now, but VLOOKUP should do the trick. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use the INDIRECT function. This takes a string and converts it into a range

More info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)

```
=INDIRECT("K"&A2)
```

---

But it's preferable to use INDEX as it is less volatile.

```
=INDEX(K:K,A2)
```

This returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range

More info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/index-function-HP010069831.aspx)

Put either function into cell B2 and fill down.

Comment: Your answer is not Clear. What is K (assuming column) what is A2? and where is sheet reference?

Comment: @BobSort Did you read the question that was posted? K is obviously a column, A2 is a cell that is also referenced in the question.. And neither `INDEX` OR `INDIRECT` require the sheet reference so I omitted it..