# how to reference a specific cell in a formula if other cells match a specific value

Tags: excel, formula

Thanks so much for looking at my question! I am trying to create a formula that subtracts a specific value from another formula. However, that specific value may change.

Example:

```
A       B      C      D 

1       1      100    =(2000 - ( if A = 1, i want to subtract the C value where B =1))

1       2      250

1       3      310

1       4       .

2       1

2       2                =((2000 - ( if A = 2, i want to subtract the C value where B =1))

2       3

2       4 

3       1

3       2

3       3

3       4
```

(A,B,C,D are the columns)

Hopefully this makes sense! I am trying to subtract the C value that goes along with the B1 value for each different A.

I was thinking an index match of some sort but wasnt exactly sure how to do that when the A's change. Thanks so much in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

INDIRECT or INDEX functions can help you. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283620/2440).

Comment: Sorry it is confusing. I want it to be one formula for all of column D. For example, in row 2 I would like it to be 250-100. In row 3, 310 - 100. However, when we get to the A =2, I would need it to be C6 - C5. And for A =3, it would be C12 - C9. Does that make sense? I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like a nested if function work for you here?  For example:

```
=IF(A2=1,IF(B2=1,2000-C2,"Enter calculation if B2<>1"),"Enter calculation if A2"<>1)
```

If this works, then you can simply copy/paste the function down the rows in column D.